# What is the default implementation for "shouldComponentUpdate" lifecycle method in React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A custom implementation for the `shouldComponentUpdate()` method as part of the React component lifecycle is not required.

I understand it's a boolean function that determines whether `render()` will be called upon changes in component `props` and `state`, and there are `mixins` like [PureRenderMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html) which implements the `shouldComponentUpdate()`

If no custom implementation nor mixins are provided. What's the default implementation and behavior?

Comment: As I understand it, the component renders if you don't implement this function. The function is provided to let you fine tune the rendering mechanism for special cases.

Answer (score 6):

As of React v0.13 and v0.14 the default implementation equals to `null` and as per this logic:

```
    var shouldUpdate =
      this._pendingForceUpdate ||
      !inst.shouldComponentUpdate ||
      inst.shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext);
```

the component is updated every render cycle (since `!inst.shouldComponentUpdate` evaluates to `true`).

Comment: Do you happen to know if this is still valid? I'm asking because skimming [this more recent blogpost](http://jamesknelson.com/should-i-use-shouldcomponentupdate/) suggests that the default implementation does a `deepEquals` on the new vs old props.

Comment: @bluenote10 check how it's implemented in the latest stable version: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v15.6.1/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L838 If there is no `shouldComponentUpdate` provided - components are always updated, no default implementation is provided. (unless it's a pure functional component)

Answer (score 1):

Defaults to true.

The default behaviour is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases, you should rely on the default behaviour.

shouldComponentUpdate() is invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received. Defaults to true. This method is not called for the initial render or when forceUpdate() is used.

Answer (score 0):

Given the documentation [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) the default is `true`:

> shouldComponentUpdate() is invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received. Defaults to true.